# Can I increase the resolution of a remote connection to my netbook?

Tags: windows-xp, remote-access, teamviewer

I have a Win XP netbook with a busted internal panel, and I'm planning to repurpose it as a home server of sorts.  As a first step, I installed [TeamViewer](http://www.teamviewer.com/en/download/index.aspx) (amazing cross-platform client support!) using an external monitor.

When I had the external monitor hooked up, I used hotkeys on the system itself to switch to "external only" mode, then it ran at the native resolution (720p) just fine.  Now, with the monitor disconnected, I can't find any way to get a desktop resolution other than the internal panel native, which is a lousy 1024x600.

Can I fake the system into thinking it has an external monitor connected?  If not, can I somehow coax the registry into letting me set an arbitrary resolution on the primary (internal, broken) display?  I'm not worried about damaging the panel or anything -- my 3-year-old took care of that for me :D

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I force a laptop to use a higher resolution?](http://superuser.com/questions/319149/can-i-force-a-laptop-to-use-a-higher-resolution) also [Is there any way to use a display resolution higher than the max?](http://superuser.com/questions/15140/is-there-any-way-to-use-a-display-resolution-higher-than-the-max) also [How to increase Remote Desktop resolution?](http://superuser.com/questions/240356/how-to-increase-remote-desktop-resolution)